js codes doesn't work inside react with tailwind
I am trying to make a toogle sidebar using useState but insidee className I can't implement js code and tailwind together, I can only add js codes or my tailwind codes as you can see in my codes when I try to use them together:
const Layout = () =\> {
const \[expanded, setExpanded\] = useState(true);
const toggleSidebar = () =\> { setExpanded(!expanded) };

return (
  <div className="">
    <nav className=" bg-gray-100 h-20 flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
      <img className=" h-11 w-11 rounded-sm ml-4 " src="car.jpg" alt="" />
      <a href="/profileSettings">
        <img className=" rounded-full h-12 w-12 mr-8" src="car.jpg" alt="" />
      </a>
    </nav> 
    <div className="flex h-screen">
      <aside className={(expanded ? 'w-80' : 'w-max') + "h-full"}>
        <nav className=" h-full flex flex-col bg-gray-100 border-r shadow-sm">
          <div className=" p-6 flex justify-end items-center">
            <button onClick={toggleSidebar} className={" h-6 w-6 rounded-sm hover:bg-gray-200 hover: flex items-center justify-center"}>
              <HiOutlineBars3  className=" h-8 w-8"/>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li className="flex justify-around items-center">
                <NavLink to="/dashboard"><MdHome className={(expanded? 'w-6 h-6' : 'w-6 h-6')}/></NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/dashboard">Home</NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </div>
);

};
export default Layout;

I try to use it like this {text-white ${true?'text-green-500' : 'text-red-500'}} it doesnt work

when you want to join strings together, you can use a "template literal." It looks like this: ${}.
className={`text-white ${true ? 'text-green-500' : 'text-red-500'}`}


I hoping that you want to wrapped below line in className, If yes then try below code, Below code is string formatted, In JS if you want to concat string  with dynamic variables you can use ``.
className={`text-white ${true?'text-green-500' : 'text-red-500'}`}

